# How to only allow a single connection (url/port) to read and write from a flink application

Tags: java, scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I read from a url/port perform some processing and write back to the url/port. The Url/Port allows only a single connection (of which you need to read and write when needed).

Flink can read and write to the rl port but opens 2 connections.

I have used the basic connection and from a url/port through flink

```
    // set up the streaming execution environment
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val data_stream = env.socketTextStream(url, port, socket_stream_deliminator, socket_connection_retries)
                         .map(x => printInput(x))
                          .writeToSocket(url, port, new SimpleStringSchema())
                         //.addSink(new SocketClientSink[String](url, port.toInt, new SimpleStringSchema))

    // execute program
    env.execute("Flink Streaming Scala API Skeleton")
```

The ideal solution or only solution for my case is to read and write from the same connection and not create 2 seperate connections

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You will need a JVM-Global (static) Variable for that connection and implement you own source and sink using that connection

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you please provide example code as how to implement that concept.

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to solve this outside of Flink, with an app that opens one r/w connection to the external service, and forwards that connection over two separate sockets to the flink source and sink.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comment, you have to store your connection in some static variable because your Sources- and Sinks won't use the same connection otherwise.
You must also ensure that your Source and Sink run on the same JVM using the same Classloader, otherwise you will still have more than one connection.

I built this wrapper class which holds a raw Socket-Connection and a Reader/Writer instance for that connection. Because your Source will always stop before your Sink (thats how Flink works), this class also does reconnect if it was closed before.

```
package example;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class SocketConnection implements Closeable {

    private final String host;
    private final int port;
    private final Object lock;
    private volatile Socket socket;
    private volatile BufferedReader reader;
    private volatile PrintStream writer;

    public SocketConnection(String host, int port) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        this.lock = new Object();
        this.socket = null;
        this.reader = null;
        this.writer = null;
    }

    private void connect() throws IOException {
        this.socket = new Socket(this.host, this.port);
        this.reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));
        this.writer = new PrintStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());
    }

    private void ensureConnected() throws IOException {
        // only acquire lock if null
        if (this.socket == null) {
            synchronized (this.lock) {
                // recheck if socket is still null
                if (this.socket == null) {
                    connect();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
        ensureConnected();
        return this.reader;
    }

    public PrintStream getWriter() throws IOException {
        ensureConnected();
        return this.writer;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        if (this.socket != null) {
            synchronized (this.lock) {
                if (this.socket != null) {
                    this.reader.close();
                    this.reader = null;

                    this.writer.close();
                    this.writer = null;

                    this.socket.close();
                    this.socket = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your Main Class (or any other class) holds one instance of this class which is then accessed by both your source and your sink:

```
package example;

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;

public class Main {

    public static final SocketConnection CONNECTION = new SocketConnection("your-host", 12345);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        env.addSource(new SocketTextStreamSource())
              .addSink(new SocketTextStreamSink());

        env.execute("Flink Streaming Scala API Skeleton");
    }
}
```

Your SourceFunction could look more or less like this:

```
package example;

import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.source.SourceFunction;

public class SocketTextStreamSource implements SourceFunction<String> {

    private volatile boolean running;

    public SocketTextStreamSource() {
        this.running = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(SourceContext<String> context) throws Exception {
        try (SocketConnection conn = Main.CONNECTION) {
            String line;

            while (this.running && (line = conn.getReader().readLine()) != null) {
                context.collect(line);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        this.running = false;
    }
}
```

And your SinkFunction:

```
package example;

import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.RichSinkFunction;

public class SocketTextStreamSink extends RichSinkFunction<String> {

    private transient SocketConnection connection;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        this.connection = Main.CONNECTION;
    }

    @Override
    public void invoke(String value, Context context) throws Exception {
        this.connection.getWriter().println(value);
        this.connection.getWriter().flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        this.connection.close();
    }
}
```

Note that I always use `getReader()` and `getWriter()` because the underlying Socket may have been closed in the meantime.

Comment: I think thats the ideal way forward. Thanks for taking the time in assisting with this problem. Will try it out @codeflush.dev